# Get multiple strings from JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, swifty-json

So the JSON variable `let json = JSON(nearbyChargingSites.jsonString!)` contains the current data.:

```
{
  "timestamp" : 1626902257093,
  "superchargers" : [
    {
      "location" : {
        "lat" : 63.325319,
        "long" : 10.305137
      },
      "total_stalls" : 19,
      "distance_miles" : 10.064082000000001,
      "type" : "supercharger",
      "site_closed" : false,
      "available_stalls" : 15,
      "name" : "Leinstrand, Norway - Klett"
    },
    {
      "location" : {
        "lat" : 63.466445999999998,
        "long" : 10.91766
      },
      "total_stalls" : 16,
      "distance_miles" : 11.838984999999999,
      "type" : "supercharger",
      "site_closed" : false,
      "available_stalls" : 16,
      "name" : "Stjørdal, Norway"
    },
    {
      "location" : {
        "lat" : 63.734355000000001,
        "long" : 11.281487
      },
      "total_stalls" : 12,
      "distance_miles" : 31.206503999999999,
      "type" : "supercharger",
      "site_closed" : false,
      "available_stalls" : 11,
      "name" : "Levanger, Norway"
    },
    {
      "location" : {
        "lat" : 62.832030000000003,
        "long" : 10.009639999999999
      },
      "total_stalls" : 20,
      "distance_miles" : 44.117753,
      "type" : "supercharger",
      "site_closed" : false,
      "available_stalls" : 17,
      "name" : "Berkåk, Norway"
    }
  ],
  "congestion_sync_time_utc_secs" : 1626902199,
  "destination_charging" : [
    {
      "distance_miles" : 23.366278999999999,
      "name" : "Bårdshaug Herregård",
      "location" : {
        "lat" : 63.299208,
        "long" : 9.8448650000000004
      },
      "type" : "destination"
    },
    {
      "distance_miles" : 38.390034,
      "name" : "Fosen Fjordhotel",
      "location" : {
        "lat" : 63.959356999999997,
        "long" : 10.223908
      },
      "type" : "destination"
    },
    {
      "distance_miles" : 46.220022999999998,
      "name" : "Falksenteret",
      "location" : {
        "lat" : 63.293301999999997,
        "long" : 9.0834460000000004
      },
      "type" : "destination"
    },
    {
      "distance_miles" : 54.981445000000001,
      "name" : "Væktarstua",
      "location" : {
        "lat" : 62.908683000000003,
        "long" : 11.893306000000001
      },
      "type" : "destination"
    }
  ]
}
```

I use `SwiftyJSON` and tries to get the superchargers latitude, longitude and name, like this:

```
let jsonName = json["superchargers"]["name"]
let jsonLat = json["superchargers"]["location"]["lat"]
let jsonLong = json["superchargers"]["location"]["long"]
```

When trying to print any of those, all of them return `nil`.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong, and how to do this?

The reason I want to do this is because I want to add them as `annotation` to a `MKMapView`.

Comment: superchargers is an array and not a dictionary

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Hm, so how do I get the value from the array? Is superchargers array and location a dictionary?

Comment: I don’t know swiftyjson but I assume you need some kind of loop and yes location is a dictionary . Look up the documentation for how to loop using swiftyjson.

Comment: Conforming your struct to `Codable`should be sufficient. Not sure why you need a third party framework for this in 2021.

Comment: @Adrian Would you rather suggest I use `JSONDecoder`?

Answer (score 0):

The first error is that the JSON initializer you are using will create a single JSON string object, it will not parse the string as JSON data:

Instead of:

```
let json = JSON(nearbyChargingSites.jsonString!)
```

you need to use:

```
let json = JSON(data: dataFromJSONString)
```

Second you need to iterate over the superchargers array to collect all the values

Try something like:

```
    if let dataFromString = nearbyChargingSites.jsonString!.data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false) {
        let json = try! JSON(data: dataFromString,options: .allowFragments)

        for supercharger in json["superchargers"].arrayValue {
            let jsonName = supercharger["name"].stringValue
            let jsonLat = supercharger["location"]["lat"].doubleValue
            let jsonLong = supercharger["location"]["long"].doubleValue
        }
    }
```

Please note that the above code does not perform error handling and will crash if values are missing from JSON.

Comment: Will it be the same way if I use `JSONDecoder`? Maybe better to use that because it is included in Xcode already.

Comment: It will have the same results. It is a matter for preference and features provided by each tool. However the way to use `JSONDecoder` is not the same as `SwiftyJSON`, so you will have to lookup examples and the documentation for each one.

Comment: @Westuo did the solution I gave worked for you?

Comment: Ok, reason for asking is because I've had so much trouble earlier with `SwiftyJSON`.

Comment: The solution you have me does not return any value. I tried adding `print("jsonLong: \(jsonLong)")` after `let jsonLong ...`, but nothing printed in the console.

Comment: @Westuo Please provide me with the exact print of the value of nearbyChargingSites.jsonString. You can update the description in the question.

Comment: Updated the question with the exact print I get from: `print(nearbyChargingSites.jsonString!)`

Comment: @Westuo I have updated my answer based on the JSON you provided

Comment: Now I just repeatedly get `RESPONSE BODY ERROR: Retry later` for each `SwiftyJSON` call I make. Can you post the example using `JSONDecoder` instead, please? Or is that too much work?

Comment: @Westuo I think the error indicates that it is irrelevant with JSON parsing. The error probably is from the service you are calling to retrieve the data. Check the contents of nearbyChargingSites.jsonString!

Comment: The content of `nearbyChargingSites.jsonString!` is still the same, because that is stored already. I tried again now, and still get the same print as in the question, and also the message `RESPONSE BODY ERROR: Retry later `.

Comment: @Westuo the code I provided works as expected you can check it here https://github.com/csknns/SwiftyJSONExample